# Прилагательные, оканчивающиеся на ...ичный

Tags: математика, орфография, сокращения

Очень интересует, можно ли заменять цифрами часть букв в словах такого типа. Есть "двоичный", "троичный" написать несложно, то "шестнадцатеричный" при частом употреблении в тексте уже хочется сократить. Но как? 16-чный? 16-ричный? Оба варианта мне не нравятся, но то ли правда нехорошо, то ли просто с непривычки...
Можно, конечно, писать полностью по-русски, но вот попалось в тексте слово "q-ичный" -- и тут я в растерянности, и не денешься никуда. С одной стороны, можно последовать рекомендациям по наращению порядковых числительных и сделать наращивание с согласной, но тогда какой-то кучный получается...
Что посоветуете, коллеги?

Comment: 16-чный читается как "шестнадцатичный" без "ри".

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку лишь порядковым числительным, да и то, исключая римское написание, "позволено" иметь наращение, то такого правила и надо держаться. Если "...шестнадцатеричный" при частом употреблении в тексте уже хочется сократить...", то следует начать (для простоты восприятия написанного!) избегать частое употребление.

В отдельном тексте можно прибегнуть к обозначенному в его преамбуле сокращению, вроде: восьмеричная система счисления - (8СС), и далее его дублировать. Уверен, в технических текстах своя культура имеется.

Answer (score 0):

16-иричный?

Вообще, обычно числа обозначаются специальным образом, чтобы указать систему счисления. В языках программирования используют префиксы (0x - шестнадцатиричная, 0b - двоичная, 0o - восьмеричная, без префикса - десятичная). В литературе иногда используют нижний индекс, справа (в LO Math: "1234_10" - это "1234, система счисления десятичная", "1234_16" - это "1234, система счисления шестнадцатеричная"; как это делается в TeX, я не помню уже).